# jQuery Validation Engine plugin is not working in wordpress custom page template

Tags: php, wordpress, jquery-validation-engine

I am using a custom page template and including jQuery Validation Engine plugin after the 
`<!--Content Row-->` comment, the code is as follows

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php //Template Name:test ?>
<div class="wrap">

<!-- Slider -->
<?php AwesomeSlider(); ?>

<?php
    $titleType    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'intro_type', true);
    $pageTitle    = '';
    $pageDesc     = '';

    switch ($titleType) {
        case "2":
            $pageTitle    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'intro_title', true);
            break;
        case "3":
        {
            $pageTitle    = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'intro_title', true);
            $pageDesc     = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'intro_desc', true);
            break;
        }
        default:
            $pageTitle = get_the_title();
            break;
    }
?>
    <!--Intro-->
    <?php if($titleType != '4'){ ?>
    <div id="wrap_intro" >
        <div class="container">
            <div class="intro">
                <h1><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></h1>
                <h3><?php echo $pageDesc; ?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <!--Content-->
    <div id="wrap_main" >
        <div class="top_left"></div>
        <div id="main" class="container">
            <!--Content Row-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/languages/jquery.validationEngine-en.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script> 
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach');
        });
    </script>
<form id="formID" class="rmular" method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                IP Address
            </legend>
            <label>
                <span>IP: </span>
                <input value="192.168.3." class="validate[required,custom[ipv4]] text-input" type="text" name="ip" id="ip" />
            </label>
        </fieldset><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Validate &amp; Send the form!"/><hr/>
    </form>
            <div class="row">
                <?php 
                    $pageClass = 'span9';

                    if(opt('sidebar_position') == 0)
                        $pageClass = 'span12';
                    if(opt('sidebar_position') == 1)
                        $pageClass .= ' blog_right';    
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $pageClass; ?>">

                <?php 
                if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post(); 
                ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php
                    }//While have_posts
                }//If have_posts
                ?>

                    <!--Comments-->
                    <?php comments_template('', true); ?>
                </div>

                <!--Sidebar-->
                <?php 
                if(opt('sidebar_position') != 0)
                    get_sidebar(); 
                ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have tried everything but I can't seem to figure out how to make it work, I have also checked other stackoverflow answers on same situation but what error they are telling I cannot find them in my code please help me out because I need IPV4 validation for my site and I can't seem to figure out why it is not working.

Comment: How is the code failing?

Comment: Have you checked  to see if bloginfo('template_url'); is actually returning the directory you want?  There are a few alternatives if not like get_template_directory_uri()

Comment: @joshua, even after copy pasting the code from demo html document provided with validation engine validation is not working in the wordpress.
Neil, Yes I have checked by echoing the result of bloginfo('template_url'); it is working fine..

Comment: Cam you use chrome dev tools or firebug to find out what JS errors or warnings you are getting (try the console tab in chrome) and report back?  Also, is the get_header() function declaring any additional (duplicate or conflicting) jquery files, etc?

Comment: @NeilNeyman I have tried firebug console but it is of no use, it is declaring no significant errors, and get_header() has no conflicting declarations.

Comment: @NeilNeyman I have recently figured following error.
TypeError: jQuery(...).validationEngine is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach');

is this the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like there can be several causes of that.  One other thing: **<form id="formID" class="rmular"** What is happening in the CSS for the rmular class? Is everything valid there?  validationEngine is picky about stuff..

Comment: @NeilNeyman I am using validation engine default css file **validationEngine.jquery.css** and it contains no definition for using class name given to form, you can view it here http://pastebin.com/Rizx4aYU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using script tags, try the wordpress php methods for calling jQuery:

```
<?php

   wp_register_style('validation-css',
        get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/validationEngine.jquery.css",
        false);
   wp_enqueue_style('validation-css');

   //do the same for that form stylesheet with the formular class if you need it 

    /*******
   // Only include this commented section if you really need 
   // that specific version of jQuery for validationEngine to work. Otherwise leave it out 
    wp_deregister_script('jQuery');
    wp_register_script('jquery',
        get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", false);
    *****/

    wp_enqueue_script('jQuery');

    wp_register_script('validation',
       get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery.validationEngine.js",
       array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('validation');

    wp_register_script('validation-language',
       get_template_directory_uri() . "/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js",
        array('jQuery'));     //not sure about that last param, also try using array('validation') ?
    wp_enqueue_script('validation-language');
 ?>
```

Comment: you might be right, but the purpose of this css is to style the error dialog that appears above the `<input type="text"/>`. But my problem is validation engine is not validating the text field at all. And to mention validation is occuring smoothly outside wordpress, with the same code.

Comment: Even with the missing CSS? I understand that the css is for styling but I've seen cases where the same error was thorwn on invalid html, etc. So was worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah, thats why I have tried replacing the CSS it is not working.

Comment: @user2671221: I updated this answer based on your statement that it was working outside wp but not in...

Comment: thanx js files are correctly including now, but i wanna ask about this  thing
        `jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#formID").validationEngine('attach');
        });`
do you think I have called the function right? or I should change something? because validation is still not occuring despite the fact javascript files are correctly included now. Do you think I am having a noConflict case?

Comment: Not sure, but you also might need to wrap an action-handler function around those enqueue/register calls.  See... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Link_a_Theme_Script_Which_Depends_on_jQuery

Comment: I am getting following error
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validationEngine'` while I can clearly see all the js files included correctly and these are the same files which are validating the IP field outside wp.
 `$("#formID").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "centerRight", scroll: false});`

Comment: http://www.ericmmartin.com/5-tips-for-using-jquery-with-wordpress/ Take a look at some of this for more about the action-hook functions...it says you may need to call noConflict() manually if you're using a diff version of jQuery

Comment: @user2671221 Can you post what you needed to add that fixed it so we can update the answer for others searching?